# How to Disable Editing in Summernotes?

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am using [summernotes](http://summernote.org/) component and what I want to do is I want to stop the user from adding characters if s(he) exceeds 2000 Chars but I couldn't figure out how to stop typing event.

What I am doing is like the following:

```
 $(".note-editable").each(function(){
           $(this).on("keyup", function(){
                var cc = $(this).text().length;
                var arr = $(this).next().attr("class").split('_');
                var q = "q"+arr[0];
                var maxChar = arr[2];
                var textarea = $('*[name^="'+q+'"]');
                var diffChar = parseInt(maxChar - cc);
               
                if(diffChar >= 0)
                {
                    $(this).next().text(diffChar + " Remaining out of " + maxChar);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).next().text("0 Remaining out of " + maxChar);
                    
                    //$(textarea).prop('disabled', true);
                    $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0,diffChar));
                }
           });
        });
```

Any Idea how to do that, I don't want to disable the cursor or destroy the summernote .. I want to let the user feel that (s)he can still edit but it won't type anything if the text exceeds 2000 chars.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30618954/1132405

Comment: I have seen this post, but I don't want to destroy it. Destroy the summernote in this case will let the user feel that (s)he can not edit again until (s)he removes one letter for example.

Comment: What I need exactly is read-only option for the summernote

Comment: Maybe this question is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018525/adding-disable-enable-methods-to-summernote-editor

Answer (score 21):

Look at [this link](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#disable-enable) from their official document.

Basically, what you need to do is:

You can disable editor by API.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('disable');
```

If you want to enable editor again, call API with enable.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('enable');
```

Now, what you can do is, use these API calls in your own code logic/algorithms to get the desired effect.

I know its an old question, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but you could use your container to find the next '.note-editable' and set its 'contenteditable' attribute to false. Worked for me.

```html
$('#summernote').next().find(".note-editable").attr("contenteditable", false);
```

Comment: I wanted to disable only certain parts of the editable area. Your answer was the solution for me. Thank you. Like that => $('.note-editable').find('.uneditable-part').each(function () { $(this).attr('contenteditable', false); });

Answer (score 10):

You should use the build-in method to do so:

```
$("#target").summernote("disable");
```

To re-enable it use:

```
$("#target").summernote("enable");
```

However, disabling edition also disables the code view button, which does not makes sense to me. Why the user cannot view (not edit) the code? We were talking about disabling edition, nothing to do with code.

So here is my workaround:

```
function disableSN(){
    $("#target").summernote("disable");

    // Enables code button:
    $(".note-btn.btn-codeview").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled");

    // When switching from code to rich, toolbar buttons are clickable again, so we'll need to disable again in that case:
    $(".note-btn.btn-codeview").on("click", codeViewClick);

    // Disables code textarea:
    $("textarea.note-codable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function enableSN(){
    // Re-enables edition and unbinds codeview button eventhandler
    $("#target").summernote('enable');
    $(".note-btn.btn-codeview").off("click", codeViewClick);
}

function codeViewClick(){
    // If switching from code view to rich text, disables again the widget:
    if(!$(this).is(".active")){
        $("#target").summernote("disable");
        $(".note-btn.btn-codeview").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    }
}
```

Please replace the `#target` selector in the code above by the one the summernote widget is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#summernote[disabled="disabled"]').next().find(".note-editable").attr("contenteditable", false);
```